# Throwing 404 error with the authoriseUrl generated from GetRefreshToken

Tags: google-dfp

I am trying to create a sample project which consumes DFP services.
Till now :
Still in authentication part :

a)  Successfully created clientId, while creating new Client Id have checked installed apps options in the Google developer console.

b) Added the clientId, clientSecret to ads.properties .

Note : Took dfp-axis-jars-and-examples-2.2.0.tar and making my changes in it[by importing project in IDE].

c) I ran into trouble while trying to paste the authoriseUrl in the browser after running GetRefreshToken.

Please find below the error :

> "The redirect URI in the request: urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob can only
>   be used by a Client ID for native application. It is not allowed for
>   the 'WEB' client type. You can create a Client ID for native
>   application in the Credentials section of the Google Developers
>   Console."

I believe I have selected the wrong applicationType while creating new ClientId .
Appreciate inputs .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closing looking at the authoriseUrl, it seemed I was sending the wrong redirectUrl.

I forgot to copy paste the redirectUrl generated from the creation of client id in the GetRefreshToken callback property:

```
private static final String CALLBACK_URL = "https://www.example.com/oauth2callback";//"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
```

No error now :).

Answer (score 1):

The above answer did not make much sense at first glance but, I have resolved this issue by simply setting a value for redirectUri. So inside of my GetRefreshToken.php file

```
$redirectUri = "http://same_url_as_the_one_listed_in_console";
```

Comment: Thanks coletrain .